# How can I get the ID of an HTML element in a JavaScript function without passing any parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, web

How can I get the ID of an HTML element in a JavaScript function without passing any parameters?

I have a HTML element:

```
<input type="text" id="exampleInput" value="0" onkeypress="exampleFunction()">
```

From JavaScript, I would like to change the value of the HTML element.

```
function exampleFunction() {
    
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this without passing the ID as a parameter?

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to your function like this:

```js
function exampleFunction(e) {
  console.log(e); // element
  console.log(e.id);  // id
  e.value = 'new value';  // change value
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="exampleInput" value="0" onkeypress="exampleFunction(this)">
```

Or, better yet, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead:

```js
document.getElementById('exampleInput').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);  // element
    console.log(e.target.id);  // id
    e.target.value = 'new value';  // change value
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="exampleInput" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the element into the function as `this`.

```js
function exampleFunction(element) {
  console.log(element.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="exampleInput" value="0" onkeypress="exampleFunction(this)">
```

Comment: You should consider to change your example. OP asked specific for the elements id. So a better example would be `console.log(element.id);` instead of `console.log(element.value);`. Please take this into account.

Comment: "From javascript, I would like to change the `value` of the HTML element."

Comment: Ok, that is right! Forget about my first comment, I stuck to the first scentence. But isn't it better to change the value whithin the callback then?